# Laravel testing without firing cache events

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, laravel-testing

I am using the array cache driver while testing, however I want to disable the Cache Events.

I can do this with

```
$this->withoutEvents();
```

I'd rather just stop the one event, however

```
$this->expectsEvents(Illuminate\Cache\Events\KeyForgotten::class);
```

will throw an error if the event is not called.

One solution would be a function that on the outside allows an event to fire and hides it but doesn't throw an error if the event doesn't occur.

I think I need to mock the Events Dispatcher like so

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher');

$mock->shouldReceive('fire')->andReturnUsing(function ($called) {
    $this->firedEvents[] = $called;
});

$this->app->instance('events', $mock);

return $this;
```

The question would be how to carry on dispatching the non caught events?

Comment: Why do you want to disable Cache Events and can they be ignored for the sake of your tests?